# Web Audio API Maximum Number of Sources?

Tags: web-audio-api, tone.js

I'm designing a web app with Electron to play back pipe organ sample files. Whenever concurrent note polyphony nears ~1024, the sound completely drops out, including subsequent reverb nodes. After the sounds would theoretically stop playing in the background (because I have released the key), the audio eventually comes back in.

Is this a hard limit on the Web Audio API? I also notice high CPU usage for that tab when it seems to be jammed.  Is there a way to enable more concurrent audio sources? Ideally, I need to have tens of thousands for proper polyphony (although many of them are the same audio files being repeated)

I'm currently looping the samples with Tone.js, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you're building an Electron app I think it should be possible to run the same code in Chrome as well. Which means you could also profile it like any other code running in Chrome.

Here is the official guide from the Chrome team on profiling: [Profiling Web Audio apps in Chrome](https://web.dev/profiling-web-audio-apps-in-chrome/).

Doing that hopefully allows you to spot any bottlenecks or performance problems in your app.